# TPieSeries and Legend with null label

Tags: delphi, teechart

I use DBChart to show pie series, but I have a problem when the value is set to NULL, the legend show the total and not an empty label.

for exemple with this code

```
with Chart1.AddSeries(TPieSeries.Create(Self)) do
  begin
    AddXY(1, 5, 'ttt');
    AddXY(1, 10, '');
  end;
```

The legend show 10 but not ''.

I have found nothing in the documentation.

Thank you

Answer (score 1):

Try changing the `Legend.TextStyle` to `ltsPlain`:

```
uses Series;

procedure TForm1.FormCreate(Sender: TObject);
begin
  with Chart1.AddSeries(TPieSeries.Create(Self)) do
  begin
    AddXY(1, 5, 'ttt');
    AddXY(1, 10, '');
  end;

  Chart1.Legend.TextStyle:=ltsPlain;
end;
```

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure what you are expecting, but this code removes the label:

```
with Chart1.AddSeries(TPieSeries.Create(Self)) do
  begin
    AddXY(1, 5, 'ttt');
    AddNullXY(1, 10, '');
  end;
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

My example is not good. In fact I use a TDBChart, so I use a SQL request to load the graphic and I have a record with a null value (some lines in the database contain null).

In my searches, I have found that using "*AddXY(1, 10, '')*" have the same effect.
In quick solution, I have change the SQL request, but I search if exists a parameter (like TreatNulls).

Comment: This is not an answer. Please edit and update your question with more details. A graph with the expected result would help, since I still don't have a clue how you would like to treat a null value from the database.